# Snake Game event.type == KEYUP: and game crashes

Tags: pygame

My code appears to get an error when I wrote the code for an event when the key is UP or unpressed, my idle runs the game and then crashes after a couple of seconds, can anyone spot a bug that I am unaware?

Obviously there's more code but at the loop is where I get the error.

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = - 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change =  10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == event.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 0

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make of your code, you are posting an if statement without any then for the statement to go on. This is creating a syntax error. Add whatever code needs to go there, and it should work.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        lead_x_change = - 10
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        lead_x_change = 10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        #  There is nothing here
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == event.K_RIGHT:
        lead_x_change = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you got values for lead_x, lead_y

```
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0
```

You need the if elif or it wont go through the choices

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            lead_x_change = -10
            lead_y_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            lead_x_change = 10
            lead_y_change = 0
```

Make sure to draw, render and update the screen

```
   gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
```

It should look something like this

```
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -10
                lead_x_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = 10
                lead_x_change = 0

    if lead_x >= 800 or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= 600 or lead_y < 0:
        gameExit = True



    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written event.K_RIGHT when it should be pygame.K_RIGHT